# Getting difficulty to focus on newly open window in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window-handles

I am unable to focus on newly open window using selenium and java.
I am using Internet explorer for running my application.
The new window is opening but not able to perform anything on the new window.
I tried with

```
Set<String> allwindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

but still issue is not resolved.

Below is the code I am using .

```
driver.get("www.tririga.com");
String parentwindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

for(String childwindow: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchto().window(childwindow);
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
    driver.close();
}

driver.switchto().window(parentwindow);
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that you are not using the first window handle to switch. You can also wait for the new window to open with explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
for(String childwindow: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!childwindow.equals(parentwindow)) {
        driver.switchto().window(childwindow);
        driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
        driver.close();
    }
}

driver.switchto().window(parentwindow);
driver.close();
```

If this is the end of your code and you just want to close all the windows just use [quit()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#quit--)

> Quits this driver, closing every associated window.

```
for(String childwindow: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!childwindow.equals(parentwindow)) {
        driver.switchto().window(childwindow);
        driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
    }
}

driver.quit();
```

Comment: No above code is not working for me. Getting index out of bond error on below line. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

Comment: @JayeshKharbas Unlikely, there is nothing in this method that can throw this exception. You can even look at the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java).